# Tesseract OCR fails to recognize number 7

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to analyze a png image containing two digits. Tesseract seems to have an issue detecting the number 7 (seven) in this image. It recognizes it as a 1 (one).

my config is:

```
config='--oem 1 --psm 7 tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
```

tesseract --version returns the following

```
tesseract 4.0.0
leptonica-1.76.0
libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.1.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
```

I've played with the oem and psm values with no change in result. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: tesseract not recognizing the number 7 (seven) digit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters in the image are too big, I guess tesseract was not trained for that.

Resizing the image works fine

```
tesseract cnLRQ.png stdout --oem 1 --psm 7 --dpi 70 digits
18
convert -resize 10% cnLRQ.png cnLRQ-small.png
tesseract cnLRQ-small.png stdout --oem 1 --psm 7 --dpi 70 digits
78
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked for this specific instance but is still not working for all my examples. However I now know i need to play with sizes and dpi as well. Thanks again!